# TailwindCSS overflow-auto class not working with React Lists

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am experiencing an issue where the overflow properties of Tailwind are not working with react lists. I am wondering if this is just a simple mistake on my part or if there is a work around that I need to do.

[Image to It Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhudb.png)

```
import CoinSummary from './CoinSummary'

const Holdings = ({ coins }) => {
  return (
    <div className='overflow-auto p-4'>
      <h2 className='text-2xl text-center font-bold mt-4'>Holdings</h2>
      {coins &&
        coins.map((coin, index) => {
          return <CoinSummary key={index} coin={coin} />
        })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Holdings
```

I want the list of coins to stay inside of the Holdings component and if it overflows, to have a scroll bar instead. However, as you can see in the photo, it doesn't seem to be working like I expected it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out on my own. It was because I did not specify the height to be h-full